# C# small caching API

Tags: c#, cache

```
public interface ICacheable<TK,TV>
{
   TV Get(TK key);
   void Add(TK key, TV val);
}

public abstract class BaseCache<TK, TV>
{
    protected static Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<TK, TV>> data = new Dictionary<Guid, Dictionary<TK, TV>>();
    private Guid StorageNameSpage;

    protected BaseCache(Guid storageNameSpage)
    {
        StorageNameSpage = storageNameSpage;
    }

    protected BaseCache()
    {
        StorageNameSpage = Guid.NewGuid();
    } 



    public TV Get(TK key)
    {
        return data[StorageNameSpage][key];
    }

    public void Add(TK key, TV val)
    {
        data.Add(....);
     }
}
```

2 different ways to implement it:

"mulityTon" or what ever you want to call it.

```
public class KeyValCacheStorage<TK, TV> : BaseCache<TK, TV>, ICacheable<TK, TV>
{

}
```

SingleTome

```
public class KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon<TK, TV> : BaseCache<TK, TV>, ICacheable<TK, TV>
{
    private static Guid storageNameSpage = Guid.NewGuid();
    public KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon():base(storageNameSpage)
    {

    }
}
```

usage:

```
KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon<string, string> storageSingleTon1 = new KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon<string, string>();
storageSingleTon1.Add("storageSingleTon1", "KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon");
storageSingleTon1.Add("bla", "yada");

KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon<string, string> storageSingleTon2 = new KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon<string, string>();
storageSingleTon2.Add("storageSingleTon2", "KeyValCacheStorageSingleTon2");
```

Comment: How is this better than having a private static dictionary elsewhere? The dictionary gives you a lot of functionality, such as it can tell you whether a key exists, it can participate in a LINQ query, etc. etc. I would rather write an algorithm against an IDictionary than ICacheable interface.

Answer (score 4):

So I've made a few modifications; here are the explanations:

- Used interfaces a bit more liberally (`IDictionary`)
- Made `BaseClass` implement `ICacheable` so the subclasses don't explicitly have to
- Made fields `readonly` as appropriate to declare intent
- Made field `data` `private` and exposed as `protected` by way of a property
- Chained the `BaseCache` constructors
- Created the storage dictionary in the constructor (could do this in `Add` if you were looking for lazy creation)
- `sealed` subclasses (if they're intended to be non-inheritable, of course)

The code:

```
public interface ICacheable<TK, TV>
{
    TV Get(TK key);

    void Add(TK key, TV val);
}

public abstract class BaseCache<TK, TV> : ICacheable<TK, TV>
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Guid, IDictionary<TK, TV>> data = new Dictionary<Guid, IDictionary<TK, TV>>();

    private readonly Guid storageNameSpace;

    protected BaseCache(Guid storageNameSpace)
    {
        this.storageNameSpace = storageNameSpace;
        data[this.storageNameSpace] = new Dictionary<TK, TV>();
    }

    protected BaseCache() : this (Guid.NewGuid())
    {
    }

    protected static IDictionary<Guid, IDictionary<TK, TV>> Data
    {
        get
        {
            return data;
        }
    }

    public TV Get(TK key)
    {
        return data[this.storageNameSpace][key];
    }

    public void Add(TK key, TV val)
    {
        data[this.storageNameSpace].Add(key, val);
    }
}

public sealed class KeyValCacheStorage<TK, TV> : BaseCache<TK, TV>
{
}

public sealed class KeyValCacheStorageSingleton<TK, TV> : BaseCache<TK, TV>
{
    private static readonly Guid storageNameSpace = Guid.NewGuid();

    public KeyValCacheStorageSingleton() : base(storageNameSpace)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One comment on the code: you will find your constructors easier to maintain if you use constructor chaining

protected BaseCache() : this(Guid.NewGuid() ) 
{
}

Now my possibly ignorant comments on other things.

- The usage is almost identical to `Dictionary<K,V>` why would I not just use a static instance of a dictionary?
- Are you sure that a single multidimensional dictionary actually preforms better than different instances of a regular dictionary? Have you done profiling on this? It seems to me unlikely (I use that in a snark-free sense, it seems unlikely but I don't know)
- There's like a 192732981923 different cache implementations already out there. Why not use one of those?
- When is this cache cleared? I don't see any options about that. That is the more interesting part of any caching API.
- The interface is similar to  `IDictionary<K,V>` but not quite the same. This might subtly break expectations. I don't think you'd loose anything in just implementing that interface.

Comment: Thanks, 
1. Because you have a singleTon mechanism "for free"  2. no, but from what I read its the same. 3. yea I know, each of everyone who wrote them has the right to start a new one, like myself. 4. yes, I added that. 5. more complex.  thank you

Comment: @sexyMF Yes you can of course implement your own, I was more wondering what requirement drove you to that and if there's another way to address it. I don't know what you mean by getting a static mechanism for free. The only difference seems to be that you don't have to write the word 'static'?